# Does a private company that is 100% financed by a bank loan have a WACC equal to the interest rate?

Tags: finance, debt, corporate-finance, cost, capital

When estimating a company's Cost of Debt for a Weighted Average Cost of Capital (WACC) calculation we normally look into its bond yield. But for a private company with 100% debt capital structure, will the cost of debt be simply equal to the interest rate? If not why?

Comment: Yes I'd appreciate that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's address your question in a canonical manner. Say that:

1. the required rate of return of (private) investors is denoted by $r$.
2. the interest rate or the cost of debt is denoted by $r_D$ (naturally [$r_D < r$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cost_of_capital))
3. the share of debt in the capital structure of the company is denoted by $X\%$
4. the corporate tax rate is denoted by $T_c$

It follows that the average cost of capital (average over equity and debt), $r'$, is such that

$r' = X\% r_D (1-T_c) + (1-X\%) r$

---

In your case, $X\% = 100\% = 1$, then $r' = r_D(1-T_c)$.

> [...] will the cost of debt be simply equal to the interest rate? If not why?

No. Because of [$T_c$, the corporate tax rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cost_of_capital#Cost_of_debt) being potentially non-zero.

Comment: Any question @Metrician ?

Comment: No that was very clear. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Metrician and keepAlive, there is another issue besides tax. As Berk & DeMarzo note in Chapter 12 of "Corporate Finance" 4th ed. (see box "Common Mistake" on p. 450), using the debt yield as its cost of capital is a mistake. This is because the interest payments and the repayment of the principal are only promised, not actual. In case of a bankruptcy, these payments may be reduced. Therefore, the actual cost of capital is lower than the interest rate.

Comment: @keepAlive, I believe there is another issue besides tax. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

@keepAlive's answer includes a good point about tax but misses another, more subtle issue. As Berk & DeMarzo note in Chapter 12 of ["Corporate Finance - 5th Global Edition"](https://www.pearson.com/se/Nordics-Higher-Education/subject-catalogue/finance/corporate-finance-5e-berk-and-demarzo.html) (see box "Common Mistake" on p. 454), using the debt yield as its cost of capital is a mistake. This is because the interest payments and the repayment of the principal are only *promised*, not actual. In case of a bankruptcy, these payments may be reduced. Therefore, the actual cost of capital is lower than the interest rate on the loan.

[image]

This issue is minor  to the point that it can be neglected for relatively safe debt (for sure if rated AAA or AA, mostly so if rated A and BBB, according to Table 12.2 on p. 454), but can become pretty significant for high-risk debt (BB and lower, ibid.).

[image]

Comment: You are indeed right. The cost of capital I compute is somehow made under a "no bankruptcy" hypothesis. +1

Comment: @keepAlive, thanks! You may want to check out a related question of mine: ["Cost of debt: How to adjust YTM for the possibility of bankruptcy?"](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/53110).